# File uploading using CodeIgniter is failing

Tags: php, codeigniter

Title says is all.

Form in view:

```
    <tr>
        <form action="<?=base_url()?>index.php/admin/product_add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <td><input type="text" name="pid"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
            <td><input type="file" name="image" id = "image"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="price"></td>
            <td><textarea name="description"></textarea></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="type"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="add">
            </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
```

Function used in controller:

```
            public function product_add()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        /*upload stuff*/
        $config = array();
        $config['upload_path'] = base_url()."imgs/products/";
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '9999';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $_POST['price']=str_replace(",", ".", $_POST['price']);
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pid','Product ID','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Denumire Produs','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('image','Imagine','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('price','Pret','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Descriere','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('type','Tip','required');

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('admin/produse', $error);
            echo "epic fail";
        }
        else
        {
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                echo "FAIL";    
            }
            else
            {
                echo "asdsad";
                $this->db_actions->addProduct($_POST["pid"],$_POST["name"],$_POST["image"],$_POST["price"],$_POST["description"],$_POST["type"]);
                redirect(base_url()."index.php/admin/produse");
            }
        }
    }
```

I've been busting my ass with this all day so I'm seriously frustrated atm.

I'm getting the error because 
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))
is indeed false. Every.Single.Damn.Time.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: just a hunch here, but this: `$config['upload_path'] = base_url()."imgs/products/";` may need to be a server path. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/imgs/products/';`

Comment: Tried it that way as well , still getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the error message not giving you anything helpful? It looks like what Kai Qing mentioned, you need to use the server (file system) path as per [EllisLab's File Upload Docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) and not the URL path.

Comment: Turns out this was it.

Answer (score 0):

here some of my codes of uploading files

function upload(){

```
            $config['upload_path']   = './files/contracts-csv/'; 
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';   
            $config['max_size']      = '4096';      
            $config['overwrite']     =  TRUE;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->display_errors('', '');

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload("image")) {
                  echo $this->upload->display_errors(); die();
                  $this->data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                 //error message
            } else {
                //do something
            }
            redirect("contracts/upload_exit");  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['upload_path'] = "var/www/your_app_images_path";
$config['allowed_types'] = "gif|jpg|png|jpeg";
$config['overwrite'] = false;
$config['remove_spaces'] = true;
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Check your upload_path it should be like above.

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload("file_fieldName")) {                        
    pr($this->upload->display_errors());exit;
}
```